# How to Plot between square of the solution and square of the term occurring in the equation?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am trying to plot between (mod[E01])^2 and (mod[as])^2 and for that using the following code as seen below. But not getting any plot. If anyone knows this, is welcome.

```
 d12 = 1;
 g1 = 0.14;
 wm = 1;
 eta = 0.1;
 C1 = 0;
 kk1 = 0.1;
 chi = 0;
 Func1 = Abs[as]^2;
 bs = -I*g1*(Func1 + C1)/(I*wm);
 sol = Solve[(I*d12 - kk1)*as - I*g1*as*(bs + Conjugate[bs]) - 
     2*I*eta*Conjugate[as]*as^2 - I*chi*Conjugate[as] + E01 == 0, as1];
Plot[{Func1 /. sol}, {E01^2, 0, 8}]
```

Comment: Change `as1`  to `as` in your Solve command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d12 = 1;
g1 = 7/50;
wm = 1;
eta = 1/10;
C1 = 0;
kk1 = 1/10;
chi = 0;
Func1 = Abs[as]^2;
bs = -I*g1*(Func1 + C1)/(I*wm);
```

Since you are plotting on the range `0 <= E01 <= Sqrt[8]` include this as a constraint to limit the solutions returned by [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) to those defined in the range of interest.

```
Length@Solve[(I*d12 - kk1)*as - I*g1*as*(bs + Conjugate[bs]) - 
    2*I*eta*Conjugate[as]*as^2 - I*chi*Conjugate[as] + E01 == 0, as]

(* 9 *)

sol = Solve[{(I*d12 - kk1)*as - I*g1*as*(bs + Conjugate[bs]) - 
       2*I*eta*Conjugate[as]*as^2 - I*chi*Conjugate[as] + E01 == 0, 
     0 <= E01 <= Sqrt[8]}, as] // Simplify;

Length@sol

(* 5 *)
```

You cannot use `E01^2` as the [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) variable

```
Plot[Evaluate[Func1 /. sol], {E01, 0, Sqrt[8]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.8, 0.4}]]
```

[image]